# Switch between panels using a button inside one of them

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a JFrame that recive the jpanels, when the program start, it recive a jpanel that  add succesfuly, but in this panel when i try to switch to another one using a button inside, nothing happens.

This my code:

this is the mainpanel

```
package Vista;


import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author harri
 */
public class MainPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainPanel
     */
    public MainPanel() {
        initComponents();
        sol();
    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panelframes = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panelframes.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(panelframes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1280, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(panelframes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 720, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    
    public void mostrarPanel(JPanel p) {
        panelframes.removeAll();//el panel principal se limpia en caso de que tenga otro jframe metido
        panelframes.add(p);
        panelframes.revalidate();//validacion en caso de error
        panelframes.repaint();//se encarga de imprimir ya lo del otro frame, acá
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainPanel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JPanel panelframes;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    
   
    
    
    public void sol() {
       mostrarPanel(new scene0());
       
       
       
    }
    
    public void loadscene1(){
        
        
    mostrarPanel(new scene1());
    
    }
}
```

this is the other 2 panles

```
package Vista;

import Vista.MainPanel;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author harri
 */
public class scene0 extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form scene0
     */
    public scene0() {
        
        initComponents();
        
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
        jLabel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        add(jLabel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
       MainPanel s = new MainPanel();
        scene1 r = new scene1();
        
        s.panelframes.removeAll();
        s.panelframes.revalidate();
        s.panelframes.repaint();
        
        
       s.loadscene1();
           
    }                                    


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

package Vista;

/**
*

- @author harri
  */
  public class scene1 extends javax.swing.JPanel {

  /**

  - Creates new form scene1
    */
    public scene1() {
    initComponents();
    }

  /**

  - This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
  - WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
  - regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // 
    private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jLabel1.setText("mamalon");
    add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 80, 190, 120));
    }//

  // Variables declaration - do not modify
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
  // End of variables declaration
  }

Comment: Please format the code at the end of your question. Keep only relevant details to show the problem, i.e. some of the comments can be cleaned up, like author.

Comment: Don't use an IDE to generate your code. The GroupLayout does not make it easy to swap components. Instead you need to use a `CardLayout`, which means you need to write the code manually to create the components and add them to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Program Works

That is, it switches panels.

The reason nothing happens when you try to switch to another panel using a button (by button you mean, `JLabel` with `MouseListener`) inside the `scene0` class is that, in your `jLabel1MouseClicked` method, you are actually creating a new instance of `MainPanel`.

So, instead of changing panels in the already visible `MainPanel`, you are changing panels in a new `MainPanel` frame.

### Solution:

Although there are other solutions, the solution that I could think for the long run is that, you should create a **Main** class in your `Vista` package. In that class you should create the instances of all your panels. Whenever, you run your program, **run this class instead of running `MainPanel` class**.

Demo-code of the **Main** class:

```
public class Main
{
 public static MainPanel mainPanel;
 public static scene0 firstScene  = new scene0();
 public static scene1 secondScene = new scene1();

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     mainPanel = new MainPanel()
   }
  });
 }
}
```

Now, whenever you are trying to access `MainPanel`,`scene0` or `scene1`, access it using
`Main.mainPanel` or `Main.scene0` or `Main.scene1`.

Modify your `jLabel1MouseClicked` method in this manner :

```
private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
  Main.mainPanel.loadscene1();         
}
```

You should also modify the `sol()` and `loadscene1()` method in this manner:

```
public void sol() {
 mostrarPanel(Main.firstScene);
}

public void loadscene1(){
 mostrarPanel(Main.secondScene);
}
```

***Note:*** The code is not tested but I am sure it will work.